# JS Variable = Razor Variable for List

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I Want filter system.

I Want select list value Variable = Razor (RFilter) variable.

Thanks for helps.

My Selectbox;

```
<select id="selector2" style="width:20vh;">
        <option v-for="(item, i) in options" :index="i" v-bind:value="item.id"> {{ item.name }}</option>
    </select>
```

My Button;

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="UAFunction(RFilter)">SEÇ</button>
```

My Function;

```
 @{
                int RFilter = 0;
                <script>
                    UAFunction(RFilter);
                    function UAFunction(RFilter) {
                        var JSFilter = document.getElementById('selector2').value();
                        var JSFilter = @RFilter;
                    }
                </script>
            }
```

My Foreach;

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                if (item.AppId == RFilter)
                {
                    <tr class="gradeU" style="text-align:center;">
                        <form action="/Home/AllList" method="POST">
                            <td><h4>@item.UserName</h4></td>
                            <td><h4>@item.UserLastName</h4></td>
                            <td><h6>@item.Question</h6></td>
                            <td><h4>@item.Answer</h4></td>
                            <td><h4>@item.CreatingTime</h4></td>
                        </form>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
```

Comment: `JSFilter` variable will always be set to 0 because `@RFilter` runs server side. It's not clear what you're asking but you're probably mixing server and client code. Also, why do you have a `form` for `td`s?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good speak English. Form not problem, my problem JS Variable = Razor Variable.